# Unprune & Re-Download Failed. Core asks for a "-reindex" due to chainstate, then fails

Tags: synchronization, reindex

I was attempting to return from pruned to unpruned chainstate. Unchecked the pruned box. Core cautioned this would require re-download of the blockchain in its entirety. OK, fine. Shutdown Core to re-start and it failed, repeatedly. Since I don't know how to -reindex, I uninstalled Core, presuming ALL data, files, directory structures, etc., associated with the program would be removed or deleted. Nope. Found the following data and structures dating to first installation:
[image: Roaming Data Folder including (pruned) blocks]

From the debug.log:

LoadBlockIndexDB(): Block files have previously been pruned

: You need to rebuild the database using -reindex to go back to unpruned mode.  This will redownload the entire blockchain. Please restart with -reindex or -reindex-chainstate to recover.

should not be overwriting a chainstate

Error: Error opening block database

Shutdown: In progress...

If I uninstall Core again, and then Delete the folders: *blocks & chainstate*, will this force another download? Or do I need to Delete the entire Roaming>**Bitcoin** folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After minimal interest and no suggestions, I decided to uninstall again, and delete the Roaming > Bitcoin folder and data. Re-installed Bitcoin Core, and am now downloading the chain again.